# Member function with strange type causing callback function mismatch

Tags: c++, ros2

I have a class where declaration and implementation are in the .cpp file.
It has a member function called `imageCallback()`, used in the constructor as seen below

```
namespace viso2_ros {

class MonoOdometer : public rclcpp::Node, public OdometerBase
{
MonoOdometer(const std::string& transport, const rclcpp::NodeOptions& options)
  {
    camera_sub_ = image_transport::create_subscription(this, "image", &MonoOdometer::imageCallback, transport, 1);
  }

protected:
  void imageCallback(
      const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr& image_msg) {
      // implementation of the image callback function
    }
}

} // end namespace
```

To me this looks ok, however it doesn't work.

The `create_camera_subscription` is expecting this signature for the callback:

```
const function<void (const shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::msg::Image_<allocator<void> > > &)>
```

but it gets this signature

```
void (viso2_ros::MonoOdometer::*)(const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr &)
```

What does this signature mean? `namespace::classname::pointer` ? Why is it not a function?

(the callback signature is the exact same one they use in the documentation https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/wiki/ROS2-Migration, if interested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That signature means it is a pointer to a *member function* rather than a regular pointer to function. In order for `MonoOdometer::imageCallback` to be called it needs an instance of the class `MonoOdometer` to call it with, but your `create_camera_subscription` just expects it to be a standalone function. Two solutions would be to either make `imageCallback` a `static` method, or pass a functor (like a lambda) which will call `imageCallback` in its own call operator.

Static:

```
static void imageCallback(...) {
  // ...
}
```

Lambda:

```
image_transport::create_subscription(this, "image",
  [&](auto& msg) { this->imageCallback(msg); }, transport, 1);
```